# Getting Java Println Outputs in PHP

Tags: java, php, arrays

I'm trying to get the output from a java application that would use the below code to output values

```
System.out.println(object.getNumber(3));
System.out.println(object.getNumber(4));
```

I'm using exec("somejavapath javaName", $output) and print_r($output) to get that output array to print.
I know it will get the values but I wanted to get into a certain format
So instead of

```
Array
(
[0] => 34
)
```

I want something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => 3
[1] => 4
)
```

Does anyone know what I could do to get this format?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want? One digit pr array-element?

Comment: Not really one digit per array element but rather for every println called to have its own array element

Comment: Shouldn't `exec($cmd, $output);` fill `$output` with one line of output being saved into one array element?

Comment: yes.. that's what I said. I was wondering if there was a way to set the format so it won't be that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not expecting comas in the output from java application , include a coma between the two values :

```
System.out.println(object.getNumber(3));
System.out.println(",");    // Print a coma in between
System.out.println(object.getNumber(4));
```

Then

```
$values_array = explode( ',', $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to break the content up using a delimiter, in this case, a line-break (`\n`).

```
$var = explode('\n', $output); // split output by line breaks
```

Comment: doesn't this only work for if the second parameter is a string?

Comment: @user1709294: Yep, and actually, it looks like `exec` already does what you want by putting each line in a separate entry in the array.